# iPhone sending ghost notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

The other day I got a notification on my iPhone, but when I went to look at what it was, there was nothing there.  I just assumed it was someone else’s phone.  Then it happened again on my desk, but there was no notification.  Again, I assumed it must have been someone else’s phone.  Today I was by myself with my AirPods in and I heard the notification sound but there is no notification.  I’m happy I’m not going crazy, but does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possibly you set an app not show in lock screen and Notification Center? Maybe look through your apps in notification settings

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  Mail was set to make noise but not show a notification.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you've set one of your apps to make sounds, but now show notifications.

To check this, scan your Notifications settings for an app that only has "Sounds" on.